# $_SESSION variables "disappear" after form is submitted

Tags: php, mysql, session

I stored values from a form in SESSION variables but it seems that they are emptied after `if(isset($_POST['submit'])` even though I can echo them earlier in my code. The code runs and the insert works except for `$toto` and `$tata` which are empty.

In the code below `_id`, `master_label`, `client_label` are inserted correctly. And the target table fields match so the error does not come from there.

```php
<?php
session_start(); 
[...]

echo "<form id='organization' action='?' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' >" ;
                    echo "<select name='organization' onchange='this.form.submit()'>";  //
                            echo '<option value="">Select ORGANIZATION</option>';
                                    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result00)) {                                                                                                                                     
                                    echo '<option value="'.$row['company_id'].'">'.$row['company_id'].'</option>';
                                    }
                    echo "</select>";
                echo "</form>";         

                $cie_ticker = $_POST['organization'] ;      
                $_SESSION['company_id'] = $cie_ticker ;

$sql="(SELECT company_id, databasefile, company_name FROM `settings` WHERE company_id='$cie_ticker') LIMIT 1"; 
$result=mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die('Could not execute the query ' . mysqli_error()) ;
$data_bis=$result->fetch_array() ;

$_SESSION['selected_cie_id'] = $data_bis['company_id'];
$_SESSION['selected_cie_name'] = $data_bis['company_name'];

            <form id='demoForm' action="?" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_top"> 
                        <?php
                        $file = fopen('./company/'.$cie_ticker.'/'.$_SESSION['selected_cie_db'], "r") ; // $file = fopen('./company/'.$_SESSION["company_id"].'/'.$_SESSION['selected_cie_db'], "r") ;
                        $headers=fgetcsv($file, 1000, "|");
                        fclose($file);
                        ?>      
                        <table id="user_table">
                            <tr><th>HEADERS </th><th>MASTER DB HEADERS</th></tr>

                            <?php foreach ($headers as $entete) {   

                                $query01="SELECT master_label FROM `mastertable`";
                                $result01=mysqli_query($connect,$query01); ?>

                                    <tr  id="<?php echo $entete;?>">
                                            <td>  <?php echo $entete ?></td>
                                            <td id="<?php echo $row['_id'];?>">
                                                    <?php                           
                                                    echo "<br>";                    
                                                        echo "<select name=".$entete.">";  
                                                                echo '<option value="MASTER DATA">Select MASTER DATA</option>';
                                                                        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result01)) {                                                                                                                                     
                                                                        echo '<option value="'.$row['master_label'].'">'.$row['master_label'].'</option>';
                                                                                                }
                                                        echo "</select>";
                                                    ?>              
                                            </td>               
                                    </tr>
                            <?php } ?>  
                        </table>
                        <input  id="checkBtn" type="submit"  name="submitbutton" value="SAVE" class="button"/>                  
                </form>
   if(isset($_POST['submitbutton'])) {          

        $toto = $data_bis['company_id'] ; 
        $tata = $data_bis['company_name']; 

        $selected=$_POST; 

        foreach($selected as $x => $x_value) {
            $query= $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO `mytable` (_id, master_label, client_label, org_label, client_id) VALUES ('',?,?,?,?) ");

            $query->bind_param('ssss',$x_value, $x, $toto, $tata  );                                    
            $query->execute();                                                                                          
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I'm betting that you didn't start the session for all files involved.

Comment: `mysqli_error()` < requires a db connection for it. `mysqli_error($connect)`

Comment: Echo Your $toto, $tata variable 1st then check..

Comment: I have started the session on top of my php:  session_start(); The db connection works.
When echoed, $toto or $tata are both empty.

Comment: It's difficult to understand the actual problem here. I suggest you make sure you can see any and all errors. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');  mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script

Comment: @Phil: It returns: Undefined index: organization in /home/public_html/myfile.php on line 61 --> which is where I have $cie_ticker = $_POST['organization'] ;

Comment: @Phil: also: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/public_html/myfile.php on line 87 -> which is where I have foreach ($headers as entete)

Comment: make sure that session_start(); is actually first line for the involved files.  Pay attention to the encoding (could be a BOM messing you up)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer: 
In this case one must add hidden input for the $_SESSION variables otherwise they were lost after submitting the form.

Comment: That should not be necessary. Something else is going on.